# How would an Alcubierre warp bubble be affected by external gravitational fields (e.g. black holes)?

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, black-holes, time-dilation, warp-drives

Consider a spaceship inside an Alcubierre warp bubble traveling in a straight trajectory. As it travels, it passes near a black hole (for the sake of argument, we'll say it's near the event horizon of a supermassive black hole, close enough that it's fairly deep in the gravity well, but far enough to avoid spaghettification). Would the black hole's gravity cause the ship's path to curve (similar to in a gravitational slingshot)?

If this is the case, would the ship also be affected by time dilation when passing through the gravity well? Or would the Alcubierre bubble provide some sort of protective effect in that regard?

Comment: An Alcubierre drive is speculative physics and relies on manipulation of exotic matter the existence of which is also entirely speculative. Either of these issues is sufficient to make this question off-topic. It *might* be salvageable if you could [edit] your question to focus on Alcubierre's metric itself and how this functions in strongly curved spacetime...